# How long can the _id string for CouchDB documents be?

Tags: couchdb

What is the maximum length for the `_id` field of CouchDB documents? Where are the specifications for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this [mail](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.couchdb.user/10905/focus=10919) on the users mailing list:

> The max size for a document is 4GB, any property (including the _id) is included in this.
>
> Also, here's another tidbit about IDs and their affect on performance: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Performance#A_id

Comment: Wayback version of wiki link can be found at https://web.archive.org/web/20161111164723/http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Performance (whether it still applies to currently supported versions of CouchDB is left as an exercise to the reader)